# Alert when someone connects to my PC

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, network-shares, monitoring

I'm sharing various folders on my Windows 7 PC. When I go to the `Computer Management` section, I can see if there are any open sessions in my shared folder. When I connect to the PC from another computer, the `Sessions` section displays information about the connecting computer, such as its IP address. Is there a way that I can get an alert pop up on my Windows 7 PC whenever a new session is opened? So, instead of me having to manually check if someone has connected to my network, I get a popup appearing stating that a new session has started with a certain computer. It would be preferable if this was possible without downloading any tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool to alert you when someone is accessing your shared folders, see this article:
[Monitor and Notify when Shared Folders being Accessed](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2007/03/11/monitor-and-notify-when-shared-folders-being-accessed/) (NetShareMonitor).

For a tool that can tell what file the user is actually accessing and can log it down for future reference:
[Track Who Modified or Deleted Files in Your Shared Folder](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/05/22/track-who-modified-or-deleted-files-in-your-shared-folder/) (System Tray Share Monitor).