# Is there a way to get Windows to provide an alert when someone logs into my computer remotely?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

Looking at the answers and comments to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/989835/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-who-has-logged-on-to-a-remote-computer), it seems that user log-ins can be monitored by checking for Event ID 4624 in the event logs.

Is there a way (through event logs, group policy, or other mechanism) to get Windows to display an alert (e.g. a popup or message in the notification area) when someone logs into the local machine?

**Note:** there is [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/346291/alert-when-someone-connects-to-my-pc) (but it is about connecting to a shared folder remotely) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/746038/how-can-i-tell-who-is-actively-logged-on-locally-or-remotely-a-windows-7-pc) (which does not specifically ask for any alert mechanism).

Comment: Is there a way out of the box: **NO**  However, that does not stop a third-party from writing software that is a watchdog and displays a notification when said event does happen.  Of course from a security perspective it is far easier to disable remote access then to write software to notify you when it happens.

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 7 (not sure about subsequent versions) you can create a scheduled task that is triggered by a specific event and that displays a message.

I have not tested this however so I am not sure how well it works and/or if it works for every type of login.

But you could do as follows, using that Event ID 4624 as an example:

Navigate to Task Scheduler (e.g. by right-clicking on "Computer" in Start Menu and selecting Manage...) and click on Create Basic Task...:

[image: Windows 7 Task Scheduler]

Give the Task at least a name:

[image]

Click Next and select "When a specific event is logged":

[image]

Click Next and select these values:

- Log: Security
- Source: Microsoft Windows security auditing.
- Event ID: 4624

[image]

Click Next and select "Display a message":

[image]

Click Next and enter the message parameters:

[image]

Click Next and Finish:

[image]